# Initializing ASP.NET Web application on application pool start

Tags: asp.net, initialization, httphandler

I have searched the web for over one day but I did not find anything I need.

I am developing an IIS web application with HttpHandlers and HttpModules. I need to initialize the application on first run (applying configuration). But I do not want to use global.asax.cs because I do not want implementations having a global.asax file in their folder (a web.config at most).

How do I run some code when the application pool is being initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the assembly level attribute PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute to have your startup code run early in the ASP.NET pipeline.

```
namespace MyWebService
{
     public class MyHttpHandler: IHttpHandler, IDisposable
     {

            public static void StartUp()
            {
                //Application Startup Code;
            }

            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                    //Do Something 
            }

            public bool IsReusable { get; private set; }

            public void Dispose(){};

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add the attribute to your AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyWebService.MyHttpHandler), "StartUp")]
```

For more info on PreApplicationStartMethod :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute